# Image manipulation - Creating characters on fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have set of designs needs to be applied to an image and saved. So if you are a user, you come to my page and add mustachio or any other face elements like hair or eyebrows to a face and save your image.

Im looking for a plugin where I can use this kind of techniques and also allow me to save it as an image on fly.

I can see a lot of masking techniques/ plugins used but I'm not sure if these techniques are capable enough to handle such a thing,

Could you please share your thoughts on this?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Where do you want the image saved; client-side or server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into the  element for creating and saving the image.

a good library that can handle multiple canvas's as layers is **EaselJS** or **FabricJS**. Both have pros and cons but can handle multiple layered images as output to one.